# CSS and images not loaded on some devices - wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, image

So I have this Wordpress-site set up:
http://dev10.xmedia.no/

One my computer and on my colleagues computer the site displays normal as it should. On my Android-phone, when in Chrome's Private Surf Mode it works at normal.

But its "screwed up" without images and CSS on the customers computer, on my phone in Chrome's normal mode and when rendering it through [Googles speed test](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=no&url=dev10.xmedia.no) its also missing.

I've set up multiple WP-sites the same way on servers with the same settings, so there should be nothing special here. Anyone got a clue why its not loaded correctly on some devices?

[image]

Comment: Its screwed on my desktop firefox too

Comment: On my desktop firefox too. All the assets return HTTP 200 codes in my network tab, so that should be alright. I see and HTML error here however: `<!-- end .off-canvas-wrapper -->`. That div is closing something that isn't there.

Comment: Are there any different plugins being used?

Comment: I've deactivated the WPML-plugin now, which is the only one I taught might have casued trouble. Fixed the extra </div>-closure aswell, but no changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS isn't being loaded because it's password protected. If you try to go directly to the stylesheet you'll see what I mean:

http://dev10.xmedia.no/wp-content/themes/fiberteam/assets/styles/style.css

Remove this block and the stylesheets will load properly.

Comment: Im not quite sure what you mean. I can access the stylesheet directly without any password - as it should - how does it look on your site?

Comment: When I try to load the stylesheet directly, I'm greeted with a page saying "To ensure that you are a real user, you will have to proceed trough this identification layer first, this is to make sure you are not trying to hack the site.
Enter the text below." and there is a captcha code to enter. I'm assuming this doesn't happen to you because you have already done it, or your IP address is whitelisted or something. Try going to the url on your mobile or a different computer to see if you get the error then.

Comment: Aaah, I see! I saw that message on another website a couple of weeks ago (same shared server). I havent seen it since, so kind of forgot about it. I have no idea where that came from, so I have contacted my hosting provider with this information. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You only load 3 stylesheets.

`style.css?ver=1`, font awesome, and the video player css.

`style.css` seems to have very little in it:

```
.wpml-ls-legacy-list-horizontal{border:1px solid transparent;padding:7px;clear:both}.wpml-ls-legacy-list-horizontal>ul{padding:0;margin:0 !important;list-style-type:none}.wpml-ls-legacy-list-horizontal .wpml-ls-item{padding:0;margin:0;list-style-type:none;display:inline-block}.wpml-ls-legacy-list-horizontal a{display:block;text-decoration:none;padding:5px 10px;line-height:1}.wpml-ls-legacy-list-horizontal a span{vertical-align:middle}.wpml-ls-legacy-list-horizontal .wpml-ls-flag{display:inline;vertical-align:middle;width:18px;height:12px}.wpml-ls-legacy-list-horizontal .wpml-ls-flag+span{margin-left:.4em}.rtl .wpml-ls-legacy-list-horizontal .wpml-ls-flag+span{margin-left:0;margin-right:.4em}.wpml-ls-legacy-list-horizontal.wpml-ls-statics-footer{margin-bottom:30px}.wpml-ls-legacy-list-horizontal.wpml-ls-statics-footer>ul{text-align:center}
```

So it looks like you just forgot to load the main stylesheet.

> UPDATE When I accessed the link to the CSS in your comment, I got a CAPTCHA. Now when I access the site, I see the site as it should look. Could **that** be your problem?

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, this is wordpress - all styles should be handled. Plus it seems that there are 9 style sheets being loaded with status 200

Comment: This is the main CSS-file -> http://dev10.xmedia.no/wp-content/themes/fiberteam/assets/styles/style.css
In my Chrome inspector (privacy mode) its loaded, together with 6 other stylesheets (I have deactivated the WPML-plugin now but didnt do any changes)

Comment: that definitely didn't load for me, there is aLOT more CSS in that file

Comment: You seem to have fixed it now?

Comment: The problem is probably the Captcha-check that comes out of nowhere. I will have to find out if thats something the hosting provider has added recently. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in the code. i have downloaded source code and put in on my local and it is working fine. it seems there is something corrupted on hosting server.

Comment: Thank you for testing that. I will indeed contact the server provider then.